# Text appears pixelated after exporting from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I'm using Illustrator CC 2018 and I wanted to make a logo for a logo challenge.

It's a horizontal logo with dimensions 400x100 px. Everything looks perfect in Illustrator, but as soon as I export it to any kind of file format results are always pixelated.

I have tried exporting it as jpeg100,jpeg80,jpeg50,jpeg20 and I get similar pixelated results every time.

After spending hours of research and countless thoughts of giving up I've decided to ask for help. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

[image: here is a screenshot of it after exporting to jpeg100][image: and second screenshot is after i zoomed in]
both of these appear to be pixelated.
I

Comment: Are you exporting the logo as a raster image like a jpg and then viewing the file larger than 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need export/import while working with Illustrator and Photoshop. You only need to do that copy whole object(or whatever) from Illustrator then paste into Photoshop workspace. Then it will open a window, select **Smart Object**

This method is the easiest way to copy/paste your works between Illustrator and Photoshop

If you want to edit object you should click it twice from **layer tab** as we did in smart object, then it will open Illustrator, when you made a change then press Ctrl+S (or save from menu), automatically update will be done in Photoshop (If my english is bad sorry...)

Answer (score 3):

You have exported the image as a raster image. File formats including: JPEGs, PNGs, TIFFs, GIFs are all raster images which are made of pixels.

Next, you opened the image in a viewer, and then you zoomed in, and now you can see the pixels.  That is exactly what happens when you zoom in on raster images!  There is nothing wrong here, it's working exactly as expected.

If you want images without pixels, you'll need to export in a vector format. SVG is ***the*** vector format for the web. Use that if you are creating graphics for a website.  The other common file format that supports vector graphics is PDF.

If you want to use raster images, that's absolutely fine, but then don't zoom in, then you won't see the pixels. If you need a bigger raster image, output at a larger size in pixels. You can do that in Illustrator when you export the graphic. Raster images should always be viewed at 100%, and NEVER zoomed in.

Comment: thank you for the valuable information.I'am new to the field i have a very little idea about exporting it to vector formats.Can you please suggest few resources where i can read about it more(if you know!)

Comment: and also most of the design platforms like Behance and social media applications only support raster image format.I can't upload a svg file on behance.What to do then?

Comment: @kj_ Then you have no option but to export as a raster image. Sometimes when uploading raster images to social media, these sites will process the images further and add more compression to keep the file size down. There's not a lot you can do at your end, except output the image at the size it is supposed to be viewed on screen. Facebook has a help page devoted to the topic of optimising your images for display: https://www.facebook.com/help/266520536764594?helpref=related

Comment: @kj_ Behance has a similar help page: https://help.behance.net/hc/en-us/articles/204484574-What-is-the-size-limit-for-uploading-files-

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting from a vector format to a raster format.

This changes the smooth vector edges to be made with pixel instead. In addition you are zooming in quite a bit which will start to display the pixels.

Just export the image at the highest quality (12) and use that.

If you do down the line need to supply a vector logo for web then you should look into [working with SVG format in Illustrator](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/svg.html).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are viewing it at 100%. When viewing your screenshot at 100%, the logo still appears clear and crisp at 400 pixels wide. When you zoom in, it will get fuzzy.

If your logo challenge allows other file formats, you can also try a vector file which will look good at any size, as it uses mathematical points instead of pixels.

Comment: You can't really use a vector format online unless the contest allows the upload of svgs or pdfs

Comment: Exactly. Who's to say it doesn't allow svgs or pdfs?

Comment: In my experience most sites just use raster image formats.